# Handling multiple parameters in a URI (RESTfully) in Java

Tags: java, rest, uri, jersey

I've been working on a small scale web service in Java/Jersey which reads lists of user information from clients contained in XML files. I currently have this functioning in all but one aspect: using multiple parameters in the URI to denote pulling multiple sets of user information or multiple sets of client information.  I have a version which currently works, but is not the best way nor what the project description calls for.

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
@Path("Client/{client}/users")
public class UserPage 
    {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String userChoice(@PathParam(value = "client") final String client) 
    {****Method here which handles a list of 'users'****}

@GET
@Path("{name}")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public String userPage(@PathParam(value = "client") final String client, @PathParam(value = "name") final String name)
    {****Method here which handles 'user' information****}
```

The first method handles a list of users from a 'client' denoted by "{client}" in the URI. The second method delivers 'user' information denoted by "{name}" in the URI.  Both will function with a single argument.  Currently, in order to handle multiple 'users' I have "{name}" comma separated like "Client/Chick-Fil-A/users/Phil,Bradley".  I can parse this after using @PathParam and create an array of these 'users', but again, I feel this is not the best way to handle this, and the project description calls for something different.

Is there a way to accomplish this same task with a URI formatted as "Client/Chick-Fil-A;cd=Phil,Bradley"? (The ;cd= is what's giving me the most trouble.)
I also need to be able to use this format for multiple clients, i.e. "Client;cd=Chick-Fil-A,Subway/users;cd=Phil,Bradley".

**Edit:** To clarify the project:
The client information is contained in 6 separate files.  Each of these files has the same 3 users (this is a proof of concept, effectively).  I need to be able to pull different subsets of information, for instance, user Phil from McDonalds and Chick-Fil-A, or users Phil and Peter from McDonalds, or users named Peter from all clients, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use '=' in the URL path since it's a reserved character. However there are many other character you can use as delimiters such as '-' and ','. So instead of '=' you can use '-'. If you really really want to use '=' then you will have to [URL-encode](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm) it; however, I would strongly recommend against this because it may make things more complicated then it should be.

You can see the grammar of the URL string here:

http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/url-spec.txt

Copy and search the following string to skip to the path grammar:

```
 path                    void |  segment  [  / path ] 

 segment                 xpalphas
```

That said, I believe HTTP request is usually used for request single resource only. So my personal opinion is to not implement the service the way you implemented. For getting multiple clients I would use query parameters as filters like this:

```
Client/{cName}/users?filters=<value1>,<value2> ...
```

**Edit:** From the business case you got there, it seems like you probably need service like

```
/users?<filters>
/clients?<filters>
```

So say you want to get Peter from all clients then can have a request of this form:

```
/users?name=Peter
```

Similarly, if you want to get Jack and Peter from Starbucks then you can do:

```
/users?name=Peter,Jack&client=Starbucks
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: It doesn't seem to me like this would work for my purpose, though.  I need to be able to access multiple users from multiple clients, which doesn't appear to be handled by these queries.

Comment: Oh I see, how about moving the client name to query parameter too?

so you have something like /users?company=<values>&user=<values> ?

Comment: After talking it over with somebody else on my project, we decided that we need to try and stay away from query parameters as much as possible. They may potentially work for this particular code, but as I mentioned, this code is more of a proof of concept. The actual code we will be writing will be more complex, so queries in the URI would become excessively complicated. I'm looking more for a more effective use of @PathParam, since @MatrixParam only works on the last segment of a URI.

Comment: Y'know what, I did end up having to use something similar to your edit's last case. I guess PathParam doesn't work as well as I thought it would...
Thanks for the suggestions for the URI.

Comment: No problem. You understand the problem you are working on better than I do, so you will make better decision than me. Glad my suggestions helped you.

Answer (score 2):

Query strings have the following syntax and you can have multiple parameters with the same name:

```
http://server/path/program?<query_string>
```

where query_string has the following syntax:

```
field1=value1&field1=value2&field1=value3…
```

For more details check out this entry in Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

Comment: I had looked into queries a bit, but it's my understanding that they cannot be used in the middle of the URI path like my last example needs.