# What would the uri(s) pointing to these methods look like

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I came across the following post at

[Handling multiple parameters in a URI (RESTfully) in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127507/handling-multiple-parameters-in-a-uri-restfully-in-java)

and i was just curious is the following a valid resource ??

```
@Path("Client/{client}/users")
public class UserPage 
{
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public String userChoice(@PathParam(value = "client") final String client) 
{****Method here which handles a list of 'users'****}

@GET
@Path("{name}")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public String userPage(@PathParam(value = "client") final String client,  @PathParam(value = "name") final String name)
{****Method here which handles 'user' information****}}
```

I especially am curious about the {name} method what uri would call the userpage method ?
how does the {} work here ?? I thought the {} was supose to enclose the name of the path class for example if the path to the class was "/Client" then it should be {client}.
Any suggestions ? IDeas ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resource you defined is valid enough, but based on the description of what you are trying to do, you need to change the source to look more like as shown below:

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/Client/{client}/users")
public interface UserPage {
   @GET
   @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
   public String userChoice(@PathParam(value = "client") final String client);

   @GET
   @Path("/{name}")
   @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
   public String userPage(@PathParam(value = "client") final String client,
         @PathParam(value = "name") final String name);
}
```

Assuming a root URI *http://www.example.com:8080*, then the following hold true:

- Invoking GET on *http://www.example.com:8080/Clients/10/users* will
  call the `userChoice` method on the resource implementation class.
  The value of `client` will be *10*.
- Invoking GET on *http://www.example.com:8080/Clients/10/users/Bob*
  will call the `userPage` method on the resource implementation class.
  The value of `client` will be *10* and the value of `name` will be *Bob*.

The curly brace syntax is used to enclose a regular expression that defines the path parameter value. Also, note that I included a leading slash ('/') on your class level path - omitting it will cause the paths not to match (in most cases).